# What is the full protocol hierarchy when using Glassfish with IIOP

Tags: rmi, corba, iiop, glassfish-2.x

The setup is **Glassfish 2.1.1** and a Java standalone client. Connection is via **IIOP**.
Our client produces an enormous amount of traffic on the wire and I'm trying to
find out where this comes from.

From my understanding the protocol hierarchy should look like

```
Ethernet -> IP -> TCP -> GIOP -> CDR
```

Up to GIOP this is what I see in Wireshark, but the payload of the
GIOP messages is unclear.

Unfortunately Wireshark doesn't dissect the payload of the GIOP-Messages.
I thought the GIOP Messages should contain Java objects 
serialized with CORBA CDR, because that is the CORBA serialization.
(After all for non Java clients, I'd had to generate IDL, so CDR should be 
used anywhere).

What I see in Wireshark is lots and lots of

```
XRMI:java.util.Collections\U0024SynchronizedCollection:
```

followed by a Hex-String and a few bytes of binary data, then again XRMI:.....

From this I suppose it's RMI and I have RMI over IIOP,
giving me

```
Ethernet -> IP -> TCP -> GIOP -> RMI -> Java Serialization
```

But if the GIOP payload is RMI where does CDR fit in.

**How can I interpret the payload of the GIOP messages and
where can I find a spec for RMI over IIOP?**

Comment: Found the RMI spec and the Java serialization spec, neither says anything about XRMI:... Where does this come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMI over IIOP is just CDR over GIOP as you have above. It's not a different protocol and it does not use Java Serialization. Its whole purpose is to be compatible with CORBA.

Comment: Ok, the CDR part of the CORBA spec defines arrays and sequences which both are serialized in a straight forward manner. It doesn't say anything about collections, though. Where does the 'XRMI:java.util.Collections\U0024SynchronizedCollection:' come from then?

Comment: @bbuser It is an 'object by value', which was added to the CORBA specification specifically for Java.